# Issue On Umbraco Grid Editor Custom Plugin

Tags: plugins, migration, editor, umbraco, umbraco8

I migrated a custom plugin that using with Umbraco 7 to 8 recently, In Umbraco 8.0.0 and Umbraco 8.1.0, It works fine. But when I try that plugin with Umbraco 8.14.1 issue is occurring.

Basically, the plugin is a media picker, after adding content to the grid editor I can select my plugin and add media to the grid Until click save or save and published which is working as expected. However, after clicking save or save and publish page is reloading and added content is missing. I can't see any error on the log file. Does anybody have an idea how to sort out his issue?

Answer (score 1):

Between 8.1.0 and 8.14.1 a *lot* of changes have obviously been made. When I compare the two versions here: https://our.umbraco.com/download/releases/compare?from=8.1.0&to=8.14.1 and search on the page for "media picker" I get 20 results.

So I guess it depends on how you implemented your custom media picker. Did you for instance copy the built in one and used it as a base? Then you might want to take a look at how the built in one looks and works now, and see if you can re-fit it into your custom one.

But since you haven't really described if you've tried fixing the issue before asking here, or provided much detail about your implementation, it's going to be difficult for us to help you (it is for me, at least) :-/

Answer (score 0):

Found that the issue occurred because of the data parsing to view through the angular custom controller. So able to fix some modifications to controller js.